# Bootstrap carousel in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with Bootstrap carousel in ng-repeat, because images are not load one by one if carousel changes, but all images are load all at onece. I found similar questions in stackoverflow, but in my case I loading data from database (not use `$scope`)

```
<div class="container"> 
   <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
       <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat="product in main.products"><a href="#"><img ng-src="../../uploads/{{ product.imagePath }}" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="item"> 
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat="product in main.products"><a href="#"><img ng-src="../../uploads/{{ product.imagePath }}" class="img-responsive"></a></div> 
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
           <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I my database I have e.g. ten products {title:'...', price:'...', description:'...' etc}, and I would like make carouse with these ten products and I would like use ng-repeat. Now in my above code carouse not working, because these ten products are views all at once

Comment: share your controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are repeating all of your images inside an item of the carousel. A carousel item is defined by the "item" class. If you want a single image to displayed at once then repeat the items like so:

```
<div class="container"> 
   <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
       <div class="carousel-inner">
          <!-- add the `active` class to the first item with one-time binding (if $index is 0) -->
          <div class="item {{::($index === 0 ? 'active' : '')}}" ng-repeat="product in main.products track by $index">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#"><img ng-src="../../uploads/{{ product.imagePath }}" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```